# Trie Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, trie

I am trying to implement the trie as shown on the [TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=usingTries) page. I am modifying it a bit to store the phone numbers of the users. I am getting segmentation fault. Can some one please point out the error.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 using namespace std;

 struct node{
int words;
int prefix;
long phone;
struct node* children[26];
 };

struct node* initialize(struct node* root) {
    root = new (struct node);   
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    root->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    root->word = 0;
    root->prefix = 0;
    return root;
 }

int getIndex(char l) {
    if(l>='A' && l<='Z'){
    return l-'A';
    }else if(l>='a' && l<='z'){
    return l-'a';
    }
 }

  void add(struct node* root, char * name, int data) {

    if(*(name)== '\0') {
        root->words = root->words+1;
        root->phone = data;
    } else {        
        root->prefix = root->prefix + 1;
        char ch = *name;
        int index = getIndex(ch);
        if(root->children[ch]==NULL)    {
            struct node* temp = NULL;
            root->children[ch] = initialize(temp);
        }
        add(root->children[ch],name++, data);
    }
 }

 int main(){
     struct node* root = NULL;
     root = initialize(root);
     add(root,(char *)"test",1111111111);
     add(root,(char *)"teser",2222222222);
         cout<<root->prefix<<endl;
     return 0;
  }
```

Added a new function after making suggested changes:

```
 void getPhone(struct node* root, char* name){
     while(*(name) != '\0' || root!=NULL) {
         char ch = *name;
         int index = getIndex(ch);
         root = root->children[ch];
         ++name;
     }
     if(*(name) == '\0'){
         cout<<root->phone<<endl;
     }
 }
```

Comment: 'homework' tag is obsolete meanwhile ...

Comment: yes .. Sorry .. :P .. changed it..

Comment: In the getIndex() function don't you mean "return l-'A'"?

Comment: yes .. was a typo changed it .. still having problem ..

Comment: A debugger will show you your error in about 1.5 seconds. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
add(root->children[ch], name++, data);
// ---------------------^^^^^^
```

To this:

```
add(root->children[ch], ++name, data);
// ---------------------^^^^^^
```

The remainder of the issues in this code I leave to you, but that is the cause of your run up call-stack.

**EDIT** OP ask for further analysis, and while I normally don't do so, this was a fairly simple application on which to expand.

This is done in several places:

```
 int index = getIndex(ch);
 root = root->children[ch];
 ... etc. continue using ch instead of index
```

It begs the question: *"Why did we just ask for an index that we promptly **ignore** and use the char anyway?"* This is done in `add()` and `getPhone()`. You should use `index` after computing it for all peeks inside `children[]` arrays.

Also, the `initialize()` function needs to be either revamped or outright thrown out in favor of a constructor-based solution, where that code truly belongs. Finally, if this trie is supposed to be tracking usage counts of words generated and prefixes each level is participating in, I'm not clear why you need *both* words and prefix counters, but in either case to update the counters your recursive decent in `add()` should bump them up on the back-recurse.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help .. But as you said there seems to be some other problem in the program .. When I use the getPhone function .. it again gives me seg fault .. I tried with the eclipse debugger .. I could not figure it out can you help?

Comment: @Fox I can take a look. I'm in the middle of something, but i'll see. Normally I'm used to tries that store subsequences (a version of trie called a [*radix tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), also called a *compact prefix trie*). I'll see if I can spot anything. Just running it under a debugger will probably show you much of what you seek though, just FYI.