# Efficient string to key matching in an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, string-matching, unordered-map

The most efficient way of mapping these strings to functions is a hash-table:

```
std::string a="/foo/", b="/foo/car/", c="/foo/car/can/", d="/foo/car/haz/";
```

Unfortunately things get more complicated when you want to match on even the most simple pattern:

```
/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+>/
/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+>/bar/[a-Z|0-9]+/
```

I have been told that the `<regex>` library is overkill for my needs; and that it's overhead is considerable.

Using a hash-table (`std::unordered_map`) here might be an efficient option; with `[a-Z|0-9]+` being checked in a single parse within a switch/case. The number of arguments (split on `/`) and using the number of `/` then any number of arguments to decide which path to take:

```
"/foo/"                  => {<function>, "/foo/can/", "/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+/bar/"}
"/foo/xflkjkjc34v"       => {<function>, "/foo/can/", "/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+/bar/"}
"/foo/can"               => {<function>, "/foo/can/", "/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+/bar/"}
"/foo/vxcvxc86vzxc/bar/" => {<function>, "/foo/[a-Z|0-9]+/bar/haz"}
```

It would be possible to implement; but is this the best approach?

Comment: Do you only have two cases (with and without bar)? How efficient do you need it to be? What's wrong with the splitting approach?

Comment: If it actually looks like the example in your second codeblock, you just need to count the number of `/`. If the function mapped does not depend on the key that maps it (meaning that there are only two functions, each one corresponding to a case), then you don't even need a hashtable.

Comment: No; those are just examples. In practise there would be many more combinations; with the RHS supporting tens of thousands of patterns. EDIT: I'll modify the example to be more specific.

Comment: Do you intend to write a switch with tens of thousands of cases?

Comment: I have a single parse implementation outputting which segments (partitioned on `/`) are in the `[a-Z]+[0-9]*` range; and which are in the `[0-9]+` range.

Comment: Let's say your address has at most N segments -- you're telling me you have two categories, and that you can label each segment with one of them, or none, correct? Then a constant length key string with N chars seems suitable to do the mapping, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal data structure would be a trie in which each slash-separated segment was matched against first a last of wildcard-free strings in an `unordered_map` or even sorted `vector` (which can be done in O(1) or O(logN) respectively), then if no match was found a `vector` of regular expressions (which you'll probably need to try one by one - O(N)).  Depending on your performance needs, you could simplify things by treating even the constant strings as regular expressions and always doing O(N) searching at each node in the trie.

```
+----------+     +---------------+                   +-----------+
| fixed:   |     | fixed:        |                   | fixed:    |
|    foo  -+---->|    bar       -|---> fn_foo_bar  --|   xxx    -|---> fn_foo_X_xxx
|    abc  -+-    |               |                /  |           |
| regexp:  | \   | regexp:       |               /   | regexp:   |
+----------+  |  |    [A-Z0-9]+ -|---------------    +-----------+
              |  +---------------+
              |
              \->+---------------+
                 | fixed:        |
                  ...
```

If you have more specific insights into the potential number of variations of fixed and reg-exp components you may well be able to optimise this further, but this is a general solution with reasonable scalability.

Comment: Thanks for that; I was considering a Trie at one point. Is there a good implementation somewhere which does most of this setup? - E.g.: [this one](http://cperea.com/programming/implementation-of-a-trie-in-c/) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16124056) or [this one](http://www.sourcetricks.com/2011/06/c-tries.html) or [this one](https://code.google.com/p/simple-trie/) or even [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18785).

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, here is what I think would be both a simple and reasonably efficient solution for your problem. This is a pseudo-code, as I don't know the specifics of your problem (what type of function you are mapping for example, etc).

```
#define MAX_SEGMENTS 255
#define LABEL_LENGTH 10
#define KEY_LENGTH (MAX_SEGMENTS*LABEL_LENGTH)
#define LABEL_FORMAT "%10u"

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Simple segment defined by position and length in a string.
 */
struct Segment
{
    unsigned pos;
    unsigned len;
};

/**
 * Example of container for regexps. 
 * This could be a tree if you had a nested structure among your regexps.
 * MyRegexp is an object that defines match( const char* segment, unsigned len )
 */
std::vector<MyRegexp> regexps;

/**
 * Mapped functions are in an unordered_map indexed by keys typically built in 
 * parse_segments below.
 */
std::unordered_map<std::string,Function*> mapped_fun;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

void split_address( const std::string& address, std::vector<Segment>& segments )
{
    // Split address into segments separated by '/'
}

void parse_segments( const std::string& address, const std::vector<Segment>& segments, char *key )
{
    // key should be of length MAX_SEGMENTS*LABEL_LENGTH.

    // Loop over all regular expressions for each segment.
    // If some regular expressions match a subset of others, then 
    // you have a tree structure among your regexps and you can 
    // exploit this structure to match your segments faster.

    // Here is an example of pseudo-code to create your key, assuming 
    // that you have a vector of regexps.   
    static char buf[ LABEL_LENGTH+1 ];
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < regexps.size(); ++i )
    if ( regexps[i].match( &address[segments[i].pos], segments[i].len ) )
    {
            sprintf( buf, LABEL_FORMAT, i );
            memcpy( key+LABEL_LENGTH*i, buf, LABEL_LENGTH );
    }
}

Function* map_address( const std::string& address )
{
    // Split address into segments
    std::vector<Segment> segments;
    split_address( address, segments );

    // Match segments to regexps
    static std::string key; key.resize(KEY_LENGTH);
    parse_segments( address, segments, &key[0] );

    // Map address to function
    return mapped_fun.find(key) == mapped_fun.end() ? 
        nullptr : mapped_fun[key];
}
```